# "buildozer -v android debug" install platform erorr

Tags: python, kivy, buildozer

I have a proplem I am using kivy to build an app on ubuntu. I am following these instructions to create a package for Android using Buildozer.

```
cd "/mnt/c/Users/c system/Documents/rak"


sudo mount -t drvfs C: /mnt/c -o metadata


buildozer init


buildozer -v android debug
```

But when I run :

```
buildozer -v android debug
```

give me erorr and this is all command

```
ali@DESKTOP-L9T54OA:~$ cd "/mnt/c/Users/c system/Documents/rak"
ali@DESKTOP-L9T54OA:/mnt/c/Users/c system/Documents/rak$ sudo mount -t drvfs C: /mnt/c -o metadata
[sudo] password for ali:


ali@DESKTOP-L9T54OA:/mnt/c/Users/c system/Documents/rak$ buildozer init
File buildozer.spec created, ready to customize!


ali@DESKTOP-L9T54OA:/mnt/c/Users/c system/Documents/rak$ buildozer -v android debug
# Check configuration tokens
# Ensure build layout
# Create directory /mnt/c/Users/c system/Documents/rak/.buildozer
# Create directory /mnt/c/Users/c system/Documents/rak/bin
# Create directory /mnt/c/Users/c system/Documents/rak/.buildozer/applibs
# Create directory /mnt/c/Users/c system/Documents/rak/.buildozer/android/platform
# Create directory /mnt/c/Users/c system/Documents/rak/.buildozer/android/app
# Check configuration tokens
# Read available permissions from api-versions.xml
# Preparing build
# Check requirements for android
# Run 'dpkg --version'
# Cwd None
Debian 'dpkg' package management program version 1.21.1 (amd64).
This is free software; see the GNU General Public License version 2 or
later for copying conditions. There is NO warranty.
# Search for Git (git)
#  -> found at /usr/bin/git
# Search for Cython (cython)
#  -> found at /home/ali/.local/bin/cython
# Search for Java compiler (javac)
#  -> found at /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac
# Search for Java keytool (keytool)
#  -> found at /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64/bin/keytool
# Install platform
# Run 'git clone -b master --single-branch https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android.git python-for-android'
# Cwd /mnt/c/Users/c system/Documents/rak/.buildozer/android/platform
Cloning into 'python-for-android'...


error: 1814 bytes of body are still expected
fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: early EOF
fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output
# Command failed: git clone -b master --single-branch https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android.git python-for-android
# ENVIRONMENT:
#     SHELL = '/bin/bash'
#     WSL_DISTRO_NAME = 'Ubuntu'
#     NAME = 'DESKTOP-L9T54OA'
#     PWD = '/mnt/c/Users/c system/Documents/rak'
#     LOGNAME = 'ali'
#     HOME = '/home/ali'
#     LANG = 'C.UTF-8'
#     WSL_INTEROP = '/run/WSL/57_interop'
#     LS_COLORS = 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.webp=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:'
#     LESSCLOSE = '/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s'
#     TERM = 'xterm-256color'
#     LESSOPEN = '| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s'
#     USER = 'ali'
#     SHLVL = '1'
#     WSLENV = ''
#     XDG_DATA_DIRS = '/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop'
#     PATH = ('/home/ali/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/home/ali/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/wsl/lib:/mnt/c/Program '
 'Files/WindowsApps/CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu_2204.1.7.0_x64__79rhkp1fndgsc:/mnt/c/Windows/system32:/mnt/c/Windows:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/OpenSSH/:/mnt/c/Program '
 'Files (x86)/NVIDIA Corporation/PhysX/Common:/mnt/c/Users/c '
 'system/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/Scripts/:/mnt/c/Users/c '
 'system/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/:/mnt/c/Users/c '
 'system/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/mnt/c/Users/c '
 'system/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin:/snap/bin')
#     HOSTTYPE = 'x86_64'
#     OLDPWD = '/home/ali'
#     _ = '/home/ali/.local/bin/buildozer'
#
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
ali@DESKTOP-L9T54OA:/mnt/c/Users/c system/Documents/rak$
ali@DESKTOP-L9T54OA:/mnt/c/Users/c system/Documents/rak$
ali@DESKTOP-L9T54OA:/mnt/c/Users/c system/Documents/rak$
```

I don't know how to check the log. Where can I find them? I am fairly new to all this so I don't think I will be able to find the error even if I read them

```
don't know how to check the log. Where can I find them? I am fairly new to all this so I don't think I will be able to find the error even if I read them
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your Ubuntu is not able to clone (download) kivy repository. First run will download a lot of stuff into .buildozer directory of your project. I also takes huge amount of time (40 minutes+, depending of your internet connection and PC specs). But next build attempts will be much quicker.

Are you using WSL (Windows Subsystem For Linux)? In other words are you installed Ubuntu from Microsoft Store? I'm curious because I see no reason for executing "sudo mount -t drvfs C: /mnt/c -o metadata" using WSL.